# Convert HEX to RGBA in Stylus

Tags: stylus

I have some HEX colour values in Stylus similar to the following

```
$my-background ?= #123456
$my-foreground ?= #ABCDEF
```

and would like to use them in rgba values for opacity, so that

```
.my-class
    background rgba($my-background, .5)
    foreground rgba($my-foreground, .5)
```

or an alternative syntax is compiled into CSS as

```
.my-class {
    background rgba(18, 52, 86, .5);
    foreground rgba(171, 205, 239, .5);
}
```

Is there a quick and easy way to use HEX colour values in rgba using Stylus or a plugin for Stylus (such as nib)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually, the `rgba` in Stylus works just like that, have you tried what you wrote? In Stylus

```
$my-background ?= #123456
$my-foreground ?= #ABCDEF

.my-class
    background rgba($my-background, .5)
    foreground rgba($my-foreground, .5)
```

Would actually compile to

```
.my-class {
  background: rgba(18,52,86,0.5);
  foreground: rgba(171,205,239,0.5);
}
```

This means you can just go and do things like `rgba(black, 0.5)`, `rgba(#FFF, 0.5)` and use variables inside of it, just like in your case.

Comment: @Metalshark I gave your question a +1 because I also didn't try it before searching the internet.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I made my own function to do this:

```
hextorgba(color, alpha = 1)
    'rgba(' + red(color) + ', ' + green(color) + ', ' + blue(color) + ', ' + alpha + ')'
```